# Order by STRING_SPLIT

Tags: mysql, sql

I'll preface this by saying I'm not too good with SQL, I have a basic knowledge but I've been trying to wrap my head around this for hours.

Lets say I have a table named Data formatted as below:

| Name | Stats |
| --- | --- |
| FirstUser | 153:54:112 |
| SecondUser | 22:75:53 |
| ThirdUser | 36:22:9 |

How can I order this by a section of Stats separated by :? e.g sorted by second section:

| Name | Stats |
| --- | --- |
| SecondUser | 22:75:53 |
| FirstUser | 153:54:112 |
| ThirdUser | 36:22:9 |

I've tried CROSS APPLY with a STRING_SPLIT, but I can't figure this out for the life of me.

Comment: Let me guess, PostgreSQL?

Comment: Mysql does not have either of cross apply or string_split. I think you have tagged the question incorrectly or tried the wrong things.